# Under what circumstances should temporaries be used C++?

Tags: c++

Under what circumstances should I use temporaries in C++?
What are the advantages of this concept?

Can anybody explain this with some examples?

Comment: voted for repopening... seems like a legit question

Comment: @Johannes : If ever 'overly broad' had a special occasion... Legit question, but too open-ended IMO.

Comment: @ildjarn i see a very specific question. he asks what temporaries are and why they exist. not sure what you deem overly broad about it.

Comment: given that most people have a wrong understanding of the term, for example wrongly believing that `int()` is a temporary, the question also is not too trivial to be closed.

Comment: There are C++-faq questions that are broader -- I don't think "why do we use this" requires an exhaustive list of every use of a temporary there has ever been, just a motivating example or two.

Comment: FWIW, the C++03 standard says in 12.2: "Temporaries of class type are created in various contexts: binding an rvalue to a reference (8.5.3), returning an rvalue (6.6.3), a conversion that creates an rvalue (4.1, 5.2.9, 5.2.11, 5.4), throwing an exception (15.1),
entering a handler (15.3), and in some initializations (8.5)". The short version is that when a function returns a class type by value, the return value is a temporary object (although it might get "elided", depending what the caller does with it). So we use temporaries because we want to return user-defined types by value.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary variables should be used when a value doesn't need to persist beyond the scope of a statement block or function definition.

There are exceptions:

1. The variable is also used outside the scope the statment block, such
   as indices in `for` loops.
2. The variable is of sufficient size that it would overrun the local
   storage (i.e. stack).
3. Large read-only data, such as character text.
4. The variable needs to be returned to the client as a reference.

Some rules of thumb or guidelines for locating variables (scope):

- Declare variables as close to their usage as possible.
- Variables referenced both inside and outside a statement block should
  be factored out of the statement block.
- Variables shared between functions should be declared with "file
  local scope" a.k.a. within the file outside any file.
- Huge variables should use dynamic memory.
- Variables larger than simple PODs should be use dynamic memory and
  passed around via smart pointers.

HTH.